# read csv file one to many relationship

Tags: javascript, java, python, excel, csv

I have 2 csv files, one looks like this:

```
summary, key, pID, Name, ID
xsajssad, abc123, 1234, p1, 12345678
yasdnalskdj, babc123, 234, p1, 312345678
zsadkmas, cabc123, 3234, p1, 212345678
```

My other csv file looks like this:

```
link
file://doc/312345678/document1.doc
file://doc/312345678/document2.doc
file://doc/12345678/document3.doc
file://soc/12345678/document1.doc
file://doc/12345678/document2.doc
file://doc/212345678/document112983.doc
```

What I want is to alter my first csv files are placed to the corressponding ID. The ID is embedded in the file link needs to map back to the unique ID in file 1. This is a one to many relationship, but I want to create a new row to match however many matches there are in the first file.

```
summary, key, projectID, projectName, ID, link
xsajssad, abc123, 1234, p1, 12345678, file://doc/12345678/document3.doc
xsajssad, abc123, 1234, p1, 12345678, file://doc/12345678/document1.doc
xsajssad, abc123, 1234, p1, 12345678, file://dpc/12345678/document2.doc
yasdnalskdj, babc123, 234, p1, 312345678, file://doc/312345678/document1.doc
yasdnalskdj, babc123, 234, p1, 312345678, file://doc/312345678/document2.doc
zsadkmas, cabc123, 3234, p1, 212345678, file://doc/212345678/document112983.doc
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: How do you know which lines in the first and second files are paired?

Comment: by the unique id that is embedded in the middle of the file link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas may be the neatest tool for this:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read the first file and declare `id` the index. Then read the second file:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv', sep=',\s*').set_index('ID')     
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
```

Extract the numeric id from the file name and set it as the index of the second dataframe:

```
df2.index = df2.link.str.split('/').str[3].astype(int)
```

Join the two tables by their indexes and convert the index back to the column:

```
result = df1.join(df2).reset_index()
result.to_csv('1.csv') # Once you do this, the original contents of 1.csv is gone!
```

Comment: i get this error: pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 1 fields in line 18, saw 2. Error could possibly be sure to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used

Comment: The script expects that the first file columns are separated by two or more spaces. If this is not true, then you must specify what the separator is. The script also expects that the second file has only one column.

Comment: the first csv is seperated by commas, so I changed sep=",", but when I run it now, I am getting this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 3: invalid start byte

Comment: Please include the _actual_ example of the file in your question, including the same text that is causing the error.

Comment: So, no errors show up anymore, but nothing changes in any of the files

Comment: Of course not. You have to write the result into a file. See updated question.  But remember: once you update 1.csv, its original content is  gone. Perhaps saving to another file is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

First read the filepath cvs file, and save into memory, and close the read (call this data set 1).

Then read the other cvs file, doing the same thing (data set 2).

Then, loop through data set 1, and for each id, select the data from data set 2, and insert into a new file.

when the loop through data set 1 is complete.  delete original file, and rename the new file - which, from a users perspective will look as though you simply modified it.

This is a simpler way to do things than modification, because inserting and modifying rows requires more logic than is necessary.

Comment: okay, i like this plan and was thinking of this originally, trying it now in python